# Highcharts does not render values received from Flask-socketio

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, flask-socketio

```
        var myChart = Highcharts.chart('containerX', {

        chart: {
          type: 'spline',
          animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
          marginRight: 10,
          events: {
              load: function () {

                  var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
                  var series = this.series[0]

                  var numbers_received = []
                  socket.on('newnumber', function(msg) {



                        var x = (new Date()).getTime() // current time
                        var y = msg.number

                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                  });                  
                 ......
```

The x-axis of Highchart is moving on my HTML page based on the `(new Date()).getTime()`, and the y-axis is scaling based on the value received from flask-socketio, but nothing is displayed on the chart.

ps: The value received is changing every seconds.

Also I can see the value `msg.number` showing on the terminal.

Can anyone help? I am new to highcharts and flask-socketio. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Berlin Bolin, Do you have any start data? http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4897/

Comment: @ppotaczek Hi. What do you mean for start data? I have data dynamically updated from socketio, and I can receive them from "msg.number" and the data is able to show on the HTML page as "text", but nothing is on the HighCharts

Comment: I mean initial data. You have set `shift` parameter in `addPoint` to true, which can cause the problem without initial data. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4900/

Comment: @ppotaczek Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have start data. But it still does not work. The Chart is shifting and the Y-value is scaling based on my `msg.number` value, but they are not showing on the graph.

Comment: Which series type do you use? What are example values for `msg.number` ?

Comment: @ppotaczek The values `msg.number` are from the remote ssh terminal over flask-socketio, which is the output data after executing a python file. The initial series is from one of the examples from HighCharts tutorial, which generates random numbers.

Comment: Could you use `console.log(msg.number)` and provide me with the result?

Comment: @ppotaczek some sample data from console.log is "0.31  0.5  0.56  0.4  0.72" and it seems fine. PS: they are not printing in the same line in console, each number is in its own line.

Comment: Please try to use: `var y = parseFloat(msg.number);`

Comment: @ppotaczek Thank you so much. It works !

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `y` values to the `addPoint` method as numbers not as strings.

```
var y = parseFloat(msg.number);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4908/